# how to read the information from json

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

i will get the json from the client and i need to get read information from the json ie MPRN=Str1234
       POBoxNumber=Str1234
      SubBuildingName=Str1234
[image]

iam using below code

```
JSONObject inputs = new JSONObject(Json); 
jsonobject = (JSONObject)
inputs.get("Request");
String mprn = jsonobject.getString("MPRN");         
String Pno = jsonobject.getString("POBoxNumber");       
String subB = jsonobject.getString("SubBuildingName");
```

iam getting the below error :

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["MPRN"] not found.
```

Comment: So, what is your question? Does the code compile and run or not? Does it do something else than you expect? If so, then what exactly did you expect and how does this differ from what it really does? Do you get an error message? If yes, then what is the error message?

Comment: Which lib? What problem occured?

Comment: iam getting the below error :    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["MPRN"] not found.

Comment: unable to read the required tags..!

Answer (score 1):

MPRN is a child of RequestBody, you need RequestBody first before you can .getString("MPRN")

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    JSONObject inputs = new JSONObject("Json");

    JSONObject requestBody = inputs.getJSONObject("RequestBody");
    JSONObject address = requestBody.getJSONObject("Address");

    String mprn = requestBody.getString("MPRN");
    String Pno = address.getString("POBoxNumber");
    String subB = address.getString("SubBuildingName");
```

Comment: thanku ,i tried but still it shows error : com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["RequestBody"] not found.

Answer (score 0):

thnaku guys...got the solution

```
 JSONObject inputs = new JSONObject(json);
 jsonobject = (JSONObject) inputs.get("Request");
JSONObject requestBody = jsonobject.getJSONObject("RequestBody");
    JSONObject address = requestBody.getJSONObject("Address");

    String mprn = requestBody.getString("MPRN");
    String Pno = address.getString("POBoxNumber");
    String subB = address.getString("SubBuildingName");
```